# When to dispose SPWeb and SPSite objects

Tags: development, spweb, spsite

I am writing code in feature receiver, and I am wondering when to dispose SPWeb and SPSite objects.

For example, I have this in my code:

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
```

Do I dispose the web object in this case? I know I should not do it if it's in SPContext, but what about properties.Feature?

My second case is, I have also a method that accepts SPSite as a parameter, so I pass myweb.Site to this method. Should I dispose the Site object I passed as below?

```
    public string doSomething(SPSite site)
        {
         //some code here
        }
```

third case, can anyone confirm that I must dispose web objects returned by OpenWeb function?

Comment: i feel like this has been covered many times, but can't find a similar post that covers your concerns

Comment: I know people "talk" about it, I found some articles like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248(v=office.12).aspx .. but not covering my cases

Answer (score 2):

**Do I dispose of the web object in this case?**

No. Do not dispose `SPFeatureReceiverProperties.Feature.Parent` , For more details check [SPFeatureReceiverProperties.Feature.Parent](https://docs.spcaf.com/v6/SPC110237_DoNotDisposeSPFeatureReceiverPropertiesFeatureParent.html)

**Should I dispose of the Site object I passed as below?**

In this case,`Site` is a reference variable type that by default passed by value in C# , So for reference type only the reference for the same object that has been copied not the entire object .

So you don't need to dispose it at the called function `doSomething`, it's sufficient to dispose it at the `originalmethod` method , so your code should look like

```
Public void originalmethod () { 

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("moss")) 
  { 

    doSomething(site); 
   }

 } 

 public string doSomething(SPSite site) {//don't dispose site object here}
```

**Can anyone confirm that I must dispose of web objects returned by OpenWeb function?**

Consider

```
SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://moss");
SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb();
```

So `OpenWeb()` will construct a new `SPWeb` object which you actually have to dispose of as

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://moss")) 
  { 
    using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb()) 
    { 
    } // SPWeb object web.Dispose() automatically called. 
  }  // SPSite object siteCollection.Dispose() automatically called.
```

Also at event receiver, it should be disposed as

```
 SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb()

  web.dispose();
```

For more details check [Disposing SPWeb and SPSite objects](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2008/12/05/disposing-spweb-and-spsite-objects/)

Comment: In the case of a method, should I dispose of the site object in the original method, or in the called method? If I dispose it in the called method? Would it that be considered as disposed in the caller method?

Comment: Dear @Jacky this good question  , you should  dispose the object at called method first as I mentioned above then dispose of the object at original method so  you can implement as the following void originalmethod () { using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://moss")) 
  { doSomething(site); } } and at doSomething(SPSite site) {//code site.dispose()} ,please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas, but isn't this the same object passed from one place to another, if you dispose it in the second method, won't it affect the first method?

Comment: but it is a class, not a primitive type, so it should be passing by reference. Right?

Comment: Dear @Jacky ,
  
  I am sorry but I need to simplify answer at this comment ,

  yes, you are right, it's not primitive type but it's also not passed by reference 

  because it's a reference type that by default passed by value in C#. 

, at reference type only the reference that has been copied not the entire object so no need for dispose within called function, this what made me confused at the above comment  :) so let me  update my answer with accurate details to be useful for all ,